# How do I create a function that takes a name with an integer suffix as argument and increases this suffix?

Tags: shell-script

I need to have the code add an argument like Brad_1 and make it into Brad_2. I am not sure how to do that because one is a number and the other is a name.

Answer (score 1):

This function accepts one parameter; it strips the string and number apart, based on the underscore, then prints back out the string plus the incremented number:

```
function increment() { 
  local num=${1#*_}; 
  local str=${1%_*}; 
  printf "%s" "${str}_$((num+1))";
}

$ echo $(increment Brad_1)
Brad_2
$ echo $(increment Jeff_41)
Jeff_42
```